# The webpage cannot be found - HTTP 404 randomly and only in IE9 (windows 7)

Tags: wordpress, windows-7, http-status-code-404, internet-explorer-9

I've googled this and can't seem to find anything.  I inherited a Frankenstein website recently that needed some changes. The site displays fine in all Firefox, Chrome and IE7 and IE8 (in Windows XP).

However, In IE9 (Windows 7), I randomly get a blank IE 404 page (not the 404 page not found file that you'd get normally) though in some cases it replaces the content with a 404 error.

Here's the site : I didn't build it so please don't judge me on the use of tables and non-standards compliant HTML and CSS.  Unfortunately the client is strapped and is not paying for a re-design.

[One Accord Trucking Jobs](http://www.oneaccordtruckingjobs.com/index2.php)

The site is a mashup of Jamit software and WordPress.

I'm really not sure why this is happening.  I can't find anything on google about IE9 doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, adding

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`

to the header files and fixing some of the horrendous markup did the trick, as near as I can tell.

There are frames, iframes and pretty crappy standards in their coding, both on the front end and on the back end.  They were using loose as a doctype! Also there were some weird conflicts with character encoding.

It was also pretty random, and one particular fix didn't help 100%, the 404 messages just happened less frequently.  I've refreshed several of the offending pages 50+ times each with not a single incidence so I'm going to say it is now fixed.

I hope my fix helps somebody else at some point.

Edit: Well, I don't know how to set this as resolved.  I guess I can't set my own answer to resolved, so perhaps somebody can post and I'll set yours as the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have WordPress integrated with external code, this sounds like a situation where `wp-blog-header.php` in WordPress may gratuitously set a 404 status header.  A workaround to this is to manually reset the status header to 200 after requiring `wp-blog-header.php`:

```
require_once('../wp-blog-header.php');
status_header('200');
```

Another workaround is for users to uncheck the Advanced setting in Internet Options called "Show friendly HTTP error messages".  If that is unchecked, then IE will behave like other browsers, which appear to ignore a 404 code in cases where content is returned from the request.